# How to apply one command into another sed command?

Tags: sed

I have one command which is used to extract lines between two string patterns 'string1' and 'string2'. This is stored in variable called 'var1'.

```
var1=$(awk '/string1/{flag=1; next} /string2/{flag=0} flag' text.txt)
```

This command works well and the output is a set of lines.

```
Do you hear the people sing?
Singing a song of angry men?
It is the music of a people
Who will not be slaves again
```

I want the output of the above command to be inserted after a string pattern 'string3' in another file called stat.txt. I used sed as follows

```
sed '/string3/a'$var1'' stat.txt
```

I am having trouble getting the new output. Here, the $var1 seems to be working partially i.e. only one line -

```
string3

Do you hear the people sing?
```

Any other suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use `sed` to extract the lines, and `awk` to insert them into the other text:

```sh
lines=$(sed -n '/string1/,/string2/ p' text.txt)
awk -v new="$lines" '{print} /string3/ {print new}' stat.txt
```

or perhaps both tasks in a single awk call

```sh
awk '
    NR == FNR && /string1/ {flag = 1}
    NR == FNR && /string2/ {flag = 0}
    NR == FNR && flag      {lines = lines $0 ORS}
    NR == FNR              {next}

              {print}
    /string3/ {printf "%s", lines}  # it already ends with a newline
' text.txt stat.txt
```

Comment: Thank you!. It works well with 'sed' to extract the lines and use 'awk' to paste it.

Comment: Suppose if need to print before the 'string3' pattern in a specific line instead of after. Can i use it like this               
 awk -v new="$lines" '{print new} /string3/ ' stat.txt

Answer (score 0):

It's a data format problem...

Appending a multi-line block of text with the `sed` *`a`ppend* command requires that every line in the block to be appended ends with a `\` -- except for the last line of that block.  So if we take the two lines of code that didn't work in the question, and reformat the text as required by the *`a`ppend* command, the original code should work as expected:

```
var1=$(awk '/string1/{flag=1; next} /string2/{flag=0} flag' text.txt)
var1="$(sed '$!s/$/\\/' <<< "$var1")"
sed '/string3/a'$var1'' stat.txt
```

---

Note that the 2nd line above contains a `bash`ism.  A more portable version would be:

```
var1="$(echo "$var1" | sed '$!s/$/\\/')"
```

Either variant would convert `$var1` to:

```
Do you hear the people sing?\
Singing a song of angry men?\
It is the music of a people\
Who will not be slaves again
```